# c++11 Why doesn't this move constructor work?

Tags: c++11, move

I've written the code posted below. I was hoping to get to move the content of a vector between instances of `LargeClass`. The move constructor is being used, but instead of moving I get copies only.

Why doesn't the move semantics work as expected here?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class LargeClass
{
public:
    explicit LargeClass (void): numbers(20, 10) 
    {
    }
    LargeClass (const LargeClass &rhs): numbers(rhs.numbers)
    { 
        std::cout << "Using LargeClass copy constructor" << '\n';
    }
    LargeClass (const LargeClass &&rhs): numbers(std::move(rhs.numbers))
    { 
        std::cout << "Using LargeClass move constructor" << '\n';
    }

    const int* getNumbersAddress(void) const
    {
        return (numbers.data());
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> numbers;
};

int main()
{
    LargeClass l1;
    std::cout << "l1 vector address: " << l1.getNumbersAddress() << '\n';

    LargeClass l2(l1);
    std::cout << "l1 vector address: " << l1.getNumbersAddress() << '\n';
    std::cout << "l2 vector address: " << l2.getNumbersAddress() << '\n';

    LargeClass l3 = std::move(l2); 
    std::cout << "l1 vector address: " << l1.getNumbersAddress() << '\n';
    std::cout << "l2 vector address: " << l2.getNumbersAddress() << '\n';
    std::cout << "l3 vector address: " << l3.getNumbersAddress() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
l1 vector address: 0x18ce010
Using LargeClass copy constructor
l1 vector address: 0x18ce010
l2 vector address: 0x18ce070
Using LargeClass move constructor
l1 vector address: 0x18ce010
l2 vector address: 0x18ce070
l3 vector address: 0x18ce0d0
```

Comment: It moves the content betwin adresses, but the addresses of containers remain the same no?

Comment: The syntax for move constructor should be `LargeClass ( LargeClass &&rhs )`

Comment: @POW please post this as an answer. What a stupid mistake... Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rvalue references don't make sense in their `const` forms because you want to modify them (you want to *"move"* them ). Objects created as `const` in C++ are in read-only memory, from which grabbing/modifying internal resources won't be possible.

The syntax for move constructor [*normally*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) should be

- `class_name ( class_name && )`

So use :

`LargeClass ( LargeClass&& rhs )`

Answer (score 3):

Although a constructor taking `const LargeClass&&` is technically known as a move constructor (12.8/3) (which is baffling, but explicitly stated in `[C++11: 12.8/3]`), it's pretty bloomin' useless; it's self-evident that you cannot *move* from a `const` expression, because you cannot modify `const` things and moving implies altering the source! In particular, you cannot *actually* move from a `const` vector, which is why that does not occur here and why you see what you see.

A more useful move constructor looks like this:

```
LargeClass(LargeClass&& rhs)
```

Comment: Strictly by the book, it *is* a move constructor. Not a very useful one, but still.

Comment: @Angew: True (12.8/3), which is bizarre.

Comment: And the move constructor is, in fact, invoked. It just doesn't do what the OP expects.